# How to create a thread to run the background every 5 secs in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code to create an alarm if a value exceeds the threshold and want that code to run in the background every 5 secs.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Name = request.getParameter("alarmName");
    String Description = request.getParameter("desc");
    String Metric = request.getParameter("name");
    String threshold = request.getParameter("threshold");
    String sign = request.getParameter("sign");

     response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       // List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Hello" +Name);
        System.out.println(Description);
        System.out.println(Metric);
        System.out.println(threshold);
        System.out.println(sign);


        try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","123");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Insert into alarmdetails(Name, Description, Metric, threshold,sign) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        System.out.println(ps);
        ps.setString(1,Name);
        ps.setString(2,Description);
        ps.setString(3,Metric);
        ps.setString(4,threshold);
        ps.setString(5,sign);
        ps.executeUpdate();   

        if(Metric.equals("cpuUsage"))
        {   
            if(sign.equals("greaterthan"))
            {
                System.out.println("reached here3");
                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select CPU_USAGE from metrics WHERE CPU_USAGE > (SELECT threshold from alarmdetails WHERE Name='"+Name+"')");
                ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();

                if(rs1.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("Alert, CPU Usage greater than threshold");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("All good");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }

        String url = "Homepage.jsp";

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

      }

      }
```

I want to run the code from `if(Metric.equals(cpuUsage))....` in a thread which runs every 5 sec.

I haven't implemented thread myself before, any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: Before you go down the route of implementing threads for this, let's look at the code you've got. You have something adding metrics into a database and then you have a worker that queries the database in order to raise an alarm. What's the context of this problem? Multiple servers doing performance counters with you querying recent changes to see if something went wrong in the last 5 seconds? This mechanism looks like it could go easily wrong in real life.

Comment: This is just for a demo purpose, @Ashley. I just want that database check to happen in the background, and whenever the value exceeds the threshold I need to alert the user.

Comment: There are examples of how to make threads in pools below. This technique won't scale at all well in real life. You'll also have to filter out situations where the peak was reached, but everything's now back to normal. Also your query will have to stay high performing while the table gets more and more full. Can you share the real problem you're trying to solve. I appreciate it's a proof of concept right now, but what will it be if it were to be completed?

Answer (score 3):

Try using ScheduledExecutorService with the specified Delay.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyRunnable(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here, the MyRunnable class would implement Runnable, and it's run method would have your processing code, without worrying about the time delays.

Comment: This is great for standalone Java. If running in a web container, then it would be better to use the container to manage the thread. Spring allows for creating threadpools and task executors.

Comment: You are not closing the connection. You should add that first.

If you are using any framework like spring, you could use their scheduling mechanism, otherwise the above mentioned code would work reasonably well, alternatively, you could look into quartz which would give you a scheduling mechanism. @AshleyFrieze could suggest more.